# How do I prevent users access to other pages in php?

Tags: php, session, hyperlink

I have a records table and I have two `user_type`: `super` and `normal`.

I want to see only selected users link on `normaluser_records.php`.

I am using session method to get user name.

**records.php**

```
echo "<tr>";
if ($_SESSION["name"]=$row[1])
{
    echo '<td align="center">'.$row[0].'-)&nbsp;<a href="players.php?id=' . $row[0] . '"$ >'.  $row[4] . "&nbsp;" . $row[5] .'</a></td>';
    echo '<td   align="center" >' . $row[6] ."". '</td>';
    echo '<td   align="center" >' . $row[7] ."". '</td>';
}
```

Notes:

`$_SESSION["name"]`: What I fetched name from `Login.php`

`$row[1]`: is the username

I know this is not right way. But I show you what I want.

Finally I'm going to use same session in `players.php`

Comment: `if ($_SESSION["name"]=$row[1])` is not a test `if ($_SESSION["name"]==$row[1])` is. But is there an actual question ?

Comment: Google for some login Tutorials. That should help. http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Comment: The easiest way is to set a flag in the session that says what privilegs your user has. Then you can simply access this flag on the spots you need it.

Example:
//login.php
$user = login($name, $password);
$_SESSION['user_group'] = $user->getUserGroup();

// some where in the view or so 
If( $_SESSION['user_group'] === 'admin' ) {
  // show admin stuff, links etc.
}else if( $_SESSION['user_group'] === 'user'){
  // ,......
} 

I hope I didn't describe it to confusing, sitting in the tram right now ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find who can login to your pages.

for example if normal_user then 
`$_SESSION['user_type']='normal'`
then select that user content
 `select * from tab where user = $_SESSION['user_type'];`
then get your data in to table.

Comment: Maybe but i want to see other records too in table but just selected user linked.